# Modal view status bar

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

[image]

I have created a modal segue which links from a view controller embedded in a navigation bar controller to a fresh new view controller which I have named "Search View Controller".

My problem is I can't seem to continue with the same red status bar as I had before. How can I change the status bar from white (nothing there) in the screenshot to red like the predecessor?

I have tried just simply adding a view with the red colour 20 pixels high which does work, but this hacky solution then creates problems when rotating to landscape.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty common problem, really. The only thing that worked for me was the hack found here: http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/09/ios-7-bugs-the-status-bar-and-modal-view-controllers/ which is slightly (but not much more) elegant :)

```
let fixItView = UIView()
fixItView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 20);
fixItView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() // your colour
view.addSubview( fixItView )
```

That's the basic idea. Try adding that small 'fixItView' to your navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks! That link is super useful. I don't suppose you could help me convert it to Swift in your answer?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment :)

Comment: Cheers! Only need to worry about it being iOS 7 and up also as it's Swift :-)

Comment: Fixed it, it's now in swift!

Answer (score 1):

as an another approach try this;

- Add an `UINavigationController` before your controller and set your controller as rootController.
- target segue to navigationController
- then hide your navigation bar if you want.